# Using sets in a list comprehension

Tags: python

what I am trying to do:
Create and print a list of words for which the reverse of the word is in the set of lower-case words.  For example, "timer" and its reverse, "remit", are both in the lower-case word list.

what i have so far:

```
     s = set(lowers)
     [word for word in s if list(word).reverse() in s]
```

i just get an empty list.

Comment: -1.  Learn to debug.  This is at least the third question today where you could try things at the command line and see your error.  The key is to break up your problem into smaller testable parts.  In this case you could have gone to the command line and tried `list('orange').reverse()` and found that it returns `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `[::-1]`, using list() is unnecessary here and `list(word).reverse()` returns `None` as it changes the list in-place . You can also use `"".join(reversed(word))`, but I guess just `word[::-1]` is simple enough:

`[word for word in s if word[::-1] in s]`

```
In [193]: word="timer"

In [194]: print list(word).reverse()
None

In [195]: word[::-1]
Out[195]: 'remit'

In [196]: "".join(reversed(word))
Out[196]: 'remit'
```

Answer (score 3):

The `list.reverse()` method reverses a list in place.  Its return value is `None`.  If you want to reverse a string just use `word[::-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

`list.reverse()` reverses the list in place and returns nothing. You need `"".join(reversed(list))`.

Comment: `reversed(list)` returns `listreverseiterator`, so he need more than just reversed(list).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = set(lowers)
[word for word in s if word.lower()[::-1] in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `[::-1]` for reversing the string -

```
[word for word in s if word[::-1] in s]
```